# How to solve this Discrete Probability Question

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

**The Question: Suppose you have a class with 30 students ‒ 10 freshmen, 12 sophomores, and 8 juniors.**

**You pick two students at random, one at a time.**

***What is the probability that the second student is a freshman, given that the first is a freshman?***

I know how to solve it in a different way, but I don't know how to solve it with Conditional Probability. So I need help solving it with Conditional Probability.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: According to the definition of a conditional probability, this probability would be equal to the ratio of the probability of the joint event to the probability of the given event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of "the second student is a freshman" given "the first student is a freshman" is the probability of both occurring simultaneously divided by the probability of "the first student is a freshman".  That is, assigning $A = {}$ "the second student is a freshman" and $B = {}$ "the first student is a freshman", and using $P$ to represent probability,
$$  P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}  $$

Now $P(B) = 10/30 = 1/3$, is easy enough to get from the given data.  One way to compute $P(A \cap B)$ is 
$$  P(A \cap B) = \frac{10}{30} \cdot \frac{9}{29} = \frac{9}{3 \cdot 29} \text{.}  $$  (This is not the only way to get this probability.)  Then 
$$  P(A|B) = \frac{\frac{9}{3 \cdot 29}}{\frac{1}{3}} = \frac{9}{29}  \text{.}  $$

Comment: Can I answer in this way ? @Eric Towers /  P(S)=P(30,2)=30!/(30-2)!=(30×29×28!)/28!=30×29=870
n(1)=10
 , n(2)=9
P(1)=n(1)/n(S) =10/30
∴P(2)=n(2)/n(S) =9/29

Comment: Without declaring what statements are $S$, $1$, and $2$, and without defining the notations $P(30,2)$, $n(1)$, and $n(2)$, I can't guess if you can answer in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F_1$ be the event that the first student is a freshman, and let $F_2$ be the event that the second student is a freshman.  Then
$$\Pr(F_2|F_1)=\frac{\Pr(F_1\cap F_2)}{\Pr(F_1)}=\frac{\binom{10}{2}}{\binom{30}{2}}\frac1{1/3}=\frac9{29}$$